# Can't save unique ID in postgres db with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, next.js, next-auth

I'm building a project utilizing nextjs and next-auth with a rails API. I have a callback that is being executed after the user has signed in with next-auth

```
export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user }) {
            const isAllowedToSignIn = true
            if (isAllowedToSignIn) {
                signInOrCreateUser({
                    account_id: user.id,
                    first_name: 'test',
                    last_name: 'test'
                })
                return true
            } else {
                // Return false to display a default error message
                return false
                // Or you can return a URL to redirect to:
                // return '/unauthorized'
            }
            
        }
    }
});
```

`signInorCreateUser()` will make a POST to my rails API but it isn't saving the unique user_id coming from the client.

```
def create
@user = User.create(
      id: params[:user_id],
      first_name: params[:first_name],
      last_name: params[:last_name],
      last_logged_in: Time.current
    )
end
```

The ID is being created in an incremental value (i.e 1,2,3,4...) but I'm looking to save this user by the ID passed in from the request. I'm able to achieve this by manually creating a `User` from the rails console but not from an incoming request. I'm guessing it has something to do with the schema of the table?

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.datetime "last_logged_in"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`id`, the primary key, is one of the [attributes_protected_by_default](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes_protected_by_default), which means that it "can never be set by mass-assignment for security reasons".

The workaround is to initialize an object, set the `id` and in the last step  invoke the `save` method:

```rb
user = User.new(
  first_name: params[:first_name],
  last_name: params[:last_name],
  last_logged_in: Time.current
)
user.id = params[:user_id]
user.save!
```

But to be honest, it feels a bit hacky. I would create a separate column where I would store `user_id` and leave `id` as an integer that will be automatically incremented.

Comment: Ok I figured. I knew that it was the primary key but was trying to test it out by manually creating the record in the console which allowed me to set whatever int value i wanted to `id`. Thanks!